# SQL Using a var as a table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this piece of code and instead of repeating the table name in each field every time I run the query, I just want to set the table name to a variable and use that, the code I have doesn't work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 DECLARE @table_name varchar(20)
 SET @table_name = 'test_table'

 IF object_id(@tableName) is not null --    object_id('TABLE_NAME')
 PRINT 'Table Exists'
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE [@tableName]( --TABLE DOES NOT EXIST, THIS WILL EXECUTE
    [ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Note] [nchar](300) NULL
)
```

This just looks for if the table exists and if it doesnt, it will create the table

Comment: Read about dynamic SQL [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql), [simple tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @Rokuto i have read a few of them but none give the solution to what i need

Comment: Because you need to adapt them to your problems :) Or just read answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic query for getting table name from variable

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(20)
 SET @table_name = 'test_table'

 IF object_id(@tableName) is not null --    object_id('TABLE_NAME')
 PRINT 'Table Exists'
ELSE
    exec('CREATE TABLE ['+@tableName+']( --TABLE DOES NOT EXIST, THIS WILL EXECUTE
    [ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Note] [nchar](300) NULL
)')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname = N'test_table';
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(1000);

IF OBJECT_ID(@tableName, 'U') IS NOT NULL --    object_id('TABLE_NAME')
    PRINT 'Table Exists';
ELSE
BEGIN
    --TABLE DOES NOT EXIST, THIS WILL EXECUTE
    SET @query = N'
    CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' (
        [ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Note] [nchar](300) NULL);';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
END;
```

You must use dynamic SQL in order to do that. Also note that I've slightly changed these:

- `@tableName` variable type to `sysname`.
- If condition to check for `'U'` (tables only)
- `QUOTENAME()`'d your table variable name, SQL Server will the ensure that it's a valid name and will prevent SQL Injection possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is what you need, something like:

```
 DECLARE @table_name varchar(20) = 'test_table'


 IF object_id(@table_name) is not null --    object_id('TABLE_NAME')
 PRINT 'Table Exists'
ELSE

exec(
'CREATE TABLE ' + @table_name +' (
[ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Note] [nchar](300) NULL
)')
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution would look like:

```
 DECLARE @table_name varchar(20)
 DECLARE @sql_statement varchar(5000)
 SET @table_name = 'test_table'

 IF object_id(@table_name) is not null --    object_id('TABLE_NAME')
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists'
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET @sql_statement = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @table_name + ' 
                         ( 
                            [ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
                            [OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
                            [Note] [nchar](300) NULL
                          )'
    EXEC (@sql_statement)
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the SQL dynamically for that. Use **sp_executesql**

The following article will be helpful: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is the thing you're looking for :

Syntax is :

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString = '<query>'
EXEC (@SQLString);
```

hence,

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(20);
SET @tableName = 'test_tbl2';
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);


IF object_id(@tableName) is not null
PRINT 'Table Exists'
ELSE
SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ['+@tableName+']( 
                        [ContactID_ContactID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
                        [OrganisationID_OrganisationID] [int] NOT NULL,
                        [Note] [nchar](300) NULL
                    )'
EXEC (@SQLString)
```